# Assetic: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)

Tags: php, symfony, sass, assetic

after cloning a symfony2 repo, when I try to compile the assets with php app/console assetic:dump the following error occurs:

[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
  An error occurred while running:
  '/Users/doe/.rbenv/shims/ruby' '/Users/doe/.rbenv/shims/sass' '--load-path' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/src/AppBundle/Resources/public/sass' '--scss' '--load-path' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/app/../web' '--cache-location' '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/app/cache/dev' '/private/var/folders/8y/9vsj9q0d5c5155sj5vgk3
  7p40000gn/T/assetic_sass5LiBb1'
  Error Output:
  ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
  Input: [sass file code here]

Could not figure out whats wrong, as path to executables are all OK. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the article that helped me to solve this issue without downgrading: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/compass-loaderror-in-assetic-and-symfony2/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+symfony%2Fplanet+%28Symfony+Blog+Planet%29&utm_medium=feed

Answer (score 1):

Found what was the problem.

By default, if you use rbenv with ruby 2.3.1 SASS gem is already installed, so which sass points you to a version of this gems that is not compatible.

The solution was:

1. Install ruby version used to build the project, `rbenv install 2.2.2`
2. Set this ruby version globally, `ruby global 2.2.2`
3. Install the SASS gem for this version, `gem install sass -v 3.4.18`
4. Get where the gems are installe, `gem env home`
5. Get the executable path for SASS gem and copy it in parameters.yml

Now `php app/console assetic:dump` it's working.